# android turning on wifi programmatically

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to turn add a wifi network programmatically and to connect to that network.

My code works fine if the wi-fi is already turned on.

If wi-fi is off, what i see wifimanager.addtonetwork() fails and when i see the wifi settings for the phone, i can see the status as scanning

If i try to connect again it works fine.

Please see code below.
Please help

```
private int changeNetwork(NetworkSetting setting) {
    // If the SSID is empty, throw an error and return
    if (setting.getSsid() == null || setting.getSsid().length() == 0) {
        return doError(R.string.wifi_ssid_missing);
    }
    // If the network type is invalid
    if (setting.getNetworkType() == NetworkType.NETWORK_INVALID) {
        return doError(R.string.wifi_type_incorrect);
    }

    // If the password is empty, this is an unencrypted network
    if (setting.getPassword() == null
            || setting.getPassword().length() == 0
            || setting.getNetworkType() == null
            || setting.getNetworkType() == NetworkType.NETWORK_NOPASS) {
        return changeNetworkUnEncrypted(setting);
    }
    if (setting.getNetworkType() == NetworkType.NETWORK_WPA) {
        return changeNetworkWPA(setting);
    } else {
        return changeNetworkWEP(setting);
    }
}

private int doError(int resource_string) {
    statusView.setText(resource_string);
    // Give up on the connection
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    if (networkId > 0) {
        wifiManager.removeNetwork(networkId);
        networkId = -1;
    }
    if (receiverRegistered) {
        unregisterReceiver(wifiReceiver);
        receiverRegistered = false;
    }
    return -1;
}

private WifiConfiguration changeNetworkCommon(NetworkSetting input) {
    statusView.setText(R.string.wifi_creating_network);
    Log.d(TAG, "Adding new configuration: \nSSID: " + input.getSsid()
            + "\nType: " + input.getNetworkType());
    WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();

    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
    config.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
    config.allowedProtocols.clear();

    // Android API insists that an ascii SSID must be quoted to be correctly
    // handled.
    config.SSID = NetworkUtil.convertToQuotedString(input.getSsid());
    config.hiddenSSID = true;
    return config;
}

private int requestNetworkChange(WifiConfiguration config) {
    statusView.setText(R.string.wifi_changing_network);
    return updateNetwork(config, false);
}

// Adding a WEP network
private int changeNetworkWEP(NetworkSetting input) {
    WifiConfiguration config = changeNetworkCommon(input);
    String pass = input.getPassword();
    if (NetworkUtil.isHexWepKey(pass)) {
        config.wepKeys[0] = pass;
    } else {
        config.wepKeys[0] = NetworkUtil.convertToQuotedString(pass);
    }
    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms
            .set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    config.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    return requestNetworkChange(config);
}

// Adding a WPA or WPA2 network
private int changeNetworkWPA(NetworkSetting input) {
    WifiConfiguration config = changeNetworkCommon(input);
    String pass = input.getPassword();
    // Hex passwords that are 64 bits long are not to be quoted.
    if (HEX_DIGITS_64.matcher(pass).matches()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "A 64 bit hex password entered.");
        config.preSharedKey = pass;
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "A normal password entered: I am quoting it.");
        config.preSharedKey = NetworkUtil.convertToQuotedString(pass);
    }
    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
    // For WPA
    config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
    // For WPA2
    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    return requestNetworkChange(config);
}

// Adding an open, unsecured network
private int changeNetworkUnEncrypted(NetworkSetting input) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Empty password prompting a simple account setting");
    WifiConfiguration config = changeNetworkCommon(input);
    config.wepKeys[0] = "";
    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    config.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    return requestNetworkChange(config);
}

/**
 * If the given ssid name exists in the settings, then change its password
 * to the one given here, and save
 * 
 * @param ssid
 */
private WifiConfiguration findNetworkInExistingConfig(String ssid) {
    List<WifiConfiguration> existingConfigs = wifiManager
            .getConfiguredNetworks();
    Log.i("Start comparing","Size "+existingConfigs.size() );
    for (WifiConfiguration existingConfig : existingConfigs) {
        Log.i("Compare with SSID", ssid + existingConfig.SSID);
        if (existingConfig.SSID.equals(ssid)) {
            Log.i("Compare success with SSID", ssid + existingConfig.SSID);
            return existingConfig;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
/*  if (intent == null
            || !intent.getAction().equals(Intents.WifiConnect.ACTION)) {
        finish();
        return;
    } */

    String ssid = intent.getStringExtra("ssid");
    String password = intent.getStringExtra("password");
    String networkType = intent.getStringExtra("type");
    setContentView(R.layout.network);
    statusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.networkStatus);

    NetworkType networkT;
    if ("WPA".equals(networkType)) {
        networkT = NetworkType.NETWORK_WPA;
    } else if ("WEP".equals(networkType)) {
        networkT = NetworkType.NETWORK_WEP;
    } else if ("nopass".equals(networkType)) {
        networkT = NetworkType.NETWORK_NOPASS;
    } else {
        networkT = NetworkType.NETWORK_INVALID;
    }

    // This is not available before onCreate
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    // Start WiFi, otherwise nothing will work
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

    // So we know when the network changes
    wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver(wifiManager, this, statusView, ssid);

    // The order matters!
    mWifiStateFilter = new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mWifiStateFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    mWifiStateFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mWifiStateFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, mWifiStateFilter);
    receiverRegistered = true;

    if (password == null) {
        password = "";
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Adding new configuration: \nSSID: " + ssid + "Type: "
            + networkT);
    NetworkSetting setting = new NetworkSetting(ssid, password, networkT);

    changeNetwork(setting);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (receiverRegistered) {
        unregisterReceiver(wifiReceiver);
        receiverRegistered = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (wifiReceiver != null && mWifiStateFilter != null
            && !receiverRegistered) {
        registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, mWifiStateFilter);
        receiverRegistered = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (wifiReceiver != null) {
        if (receiverRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(wifiReceiver);
            receiverRegistered = false;
        }
        wifiReceiver = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

/**
 * Update the network: either create a new network or modify an existing
 * network
 * 
 * @param config
 *            the new network configuration
 * @param disableOthers
 *            true if other networks must be disabled
 * @return network ID of the connected network.
 */
private int updateNetwork(WifiConfiguration config, boolean disableOthers) {
    WifiConfiguration found = findNetworkInExistingConfig(config.SSID);
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    if (found == null) {
        Log.i("WIFI","SSID NOT FOUND");
        statusView.setText(R.string.wifi_creating_network);
    } else {
        statusView.setText(R.string.wifi_modifying_network);
        Log.d(TAG, "Removing network " + found.networkId);
        wifiManager.removeNetwork(found.networkId);
        wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
    }
    networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(config);
    Log.d(TAG, "Inserted/Modified network " + networkId);
    if (networkId < 0) {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(config);
        Log.d(TAG, "Again Inserted/Modified network " + networkId);
        return FAILURE_NO_NETWORK_ID;
    }

    // Try to disable the current network and start a new one.
    if (!wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, disableOthers)) {
        networkId = FAILURE_NO_NETWORK_ID;
        return FAILURE_NO_NETWORK_ID;
    }
    errorCount = 0;
    wifiManager.reassociate();
    return networkId;
}
```

Here is my working code : ( its different from my previous code )

```
    package com.idg.project.utils;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;



/**
 * @author Vikram Aggarwal
 * @author Sean Owen
 */
public final class WifiConfigManager {

  private static final String TAG = WifiConfigManager.class.getSimpleName();

  private static final Pattern HEX_DIGITS = Pattern.compile("[0-9A-Fa-f]+");

  private WifiConfigManager() {
  }

  public static void configure(final WifiManager wifiManager, 
                               final String ssid, 
                               final String password, 
                               final String networkTypeString) {
    Runnable configureRunnable = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // Start WiFi, otherwise nothing will work
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
          Log.i(TAG, "Enabling wi-fi...");
          if (wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Wi-fi enabled");
          } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Wi-fi could not be enabled!");
            return;
          }
          // This happens very quickly, but need to wait for it to enable. A little busy wait?
          int count = 0;
          while (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            if (count >= 10) {
              Log.i(TAG, "Took too long to enable wi-fi, quitting");
              return;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Still waiting for wi-fi to enable...");
            try {
              Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
              // continue
            }
            count++;
          }
        }
        NetworkType networkType = NetworkType.forIntentValue(networkTypeString);
        if (networkType == NetworkType.NO_PASSWORD) {
          changeNetworkUnEncrypted(wifiManager, ssid);
        } else {
          if (password == null || password.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
          }
          if (networkType == NetworkType.WEP) {
            changeNetworkWEP(wifiManager, ssid, password);
          } else if (networkType == NetworkType.WPA) {
            changeNetworkWPA(wifiManager, ssid, password);
          }        }
      }
    };
    new Thread(configureRunnable).start();
  }

  /**
   * Update the network: either create a new network or modify an existing network
   * @param config the new network configuration
   * @return network ID of the connected network.
   */
  private static void updateNetwork(WifiManager wifiManager, WifiConfiguration config) {
    Integer foundNetworkID = findNetworkInExistingConfig(wifiManager, config.SSID);
    if (foundNetworkID != null) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Removing old configuration for network " + config.SSID);
      wifiManager.removeNetwork(foundNetworkID);
      wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
    }
    int networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(config);
    if (networkId >= 0) {
      // Try to disable the current network and start a new one.
      if (wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Associating to network " + config.SSID);
        wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
      } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to enable network " + config.SSID);
      }
    } else {
      Log.w(TAG, "Unable to add network " + config.SSID);
    }
  }

  private static WifiConfiguration changeNetworkCommon(String ssid) {
    WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
    config.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
    config.allowedProtocols.clear();
    // Android API insists that an ascii SSID must be quoted to be correctly handled.
    config.SSID = quoteNonHex(ssid);
    return config;
  }

  // Adding a WEP network
  private static void changeNetworkWEP(WifiManager wifiManager, String ssid, String password) {
    WifiConfiguration config = changeNetworkCommon(ssid);
    config.wepKeys[0] = quoteNonHex(password, 10, 26, 58);
    config.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
    updateNetwork(wifiManager, config);
  }

  // Adding a WPA or WPA2 network
  private static void changeNetworkWPA(WifiManager wifiManager, String ssid, String password) {
    WifiConfiguration config = changeNetworkCommon(ssid);
    // Hex passwords that are 64 bits long are not to be quoted.
    config.preSharedKey = quoteNonHex(password, 64);
    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
    config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA); // For WPA
    config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN); // For WPA2
    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    updateNetwork(wifiManager, config);
  }

  // Adding an open, unsecured network
  private static void changeNetworkUnEncrypted(WifiManager wifiManager, String ssid) {
    WifiConfiguration config = changeNetworkCommon(ssid);
    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    updateNetwork(wifiManager, config);
  }

  private static Integer findNetworkInExistingConfig(WifiManager wifiManager, String ssid) {
    List<WifiConfiguration> existingConfigs = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration existingConfig : existingConfigs) {
      if (existingConfig.SSID.equals(ssid)) {
        return existingConfig.networkId;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  private static String quoteNonHex(String value, int... allowedLengths) {
    return isHexOfLength(value, allowedLengths) ? value : convertToQuotedString(value);
  }

  /**
   * Encloses the incoming string inside double quotes, if it isn't already quoted.
   * @param string the input string
   * @return a quoted string, of the form "input".  If the input string is null, it returns null
   * as well.
   */
  private static String convertToQuotedString(String string) {
    if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    // If already quoted, return as-is
    if (string.charAt(0) == '"' && string.charAt(string.length() - 1) == '"') {
      return string;
    }
    return '\"' + string + '\"';
  }

  /**
   * @param value input to check
   * @param allowedLengths allowed lengths, if any
   * @return true if value is a non-null, non-empty string of hex digits, and if allowed lengths are given, has
   *  an allowed length
   */
  private static boolean isHexOfLength(CharSequence value, int... allowedLengths) {
    if (value == null || !HEX_DIGITS.matcher(value).matches()) {
      return false;
    }
    if (allowedLengths.length == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    for (int length : allowedLengths) {
      if (value.length() == length) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

}









    package com.idg.project.utils;



enum NetworkType {

  WEP,
  WPA,
  NO_PASSWORD;

  static NetworkType forIntentValue(String networkTypeString) {
    if (networkTypeString == null) {
      return NO_PASSWORD;
    }
    if ("WPA".equals(networkTypeString)) {
      return WPA;
    }
    if ("WEP".equals(networkTypeString)) {
      return WEP;
    }
    if ("nopass".equals(networkTypeString)) {
      return NO_PASSWORD;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(networkTypeString);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create [wifiLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#createWifiLock%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) with `WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF` mode, based on the docs it will only work with the following constraints:

> > 1. The lock is only active when the device is connected to an access point.
> > 2. The lock is only active when the screen is on.
> > 3. The lock is only active when the acquiring app is running in the foreground.

Comment: can you pls be little more elaborate . When should i create this lock

Comment: @preetha when you wish to turn wifi on, first make sure wifi is enabled network, then call Managerwifi.wifiLock(mode_full) to change the wifi mode from scaning to connecting. then call to wifiManager.reassociate() and if you have a saved enabled connection you will attempt to connect to it

Comment: i tried this one, then i was able to make connection even if wifi is off. But failed when i try with wifi on. I think some bugs in my code which i couldnt fix . I have got the solution from google. so adding that to my question.

Answer (score 28):

You can turn on/off wifi using following instructions :

```
WifiManager wManager = (WifiManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wManager.setWifiEnabled(booleanValue); //true or false
```

Set following permissions to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE">
```

**This code is deprecated in API 29 or over**

```
public boolean setWifiEnabled (boolean enabled)
**This method was deprecated in API level 29**.
```

> Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES#Q, applications are not allowed to
>   enable/disable Wi-Fi. Compatibility Note: For applications targeting
>   Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always return false and
>   will have no effect. If apps are targeting an older SDK (
>   Build.VERSION_CODES.P or below), they can continue to use this API.

Source : [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(boolean))

Comment: i have all these permissions and i always set setWifiEnabled(true).

Comment: In newer versions of Android Sdk, you will need to add Location Permission too. Also, check documentation of Android Q for change in WIFI features.