# Android - how to turn on wifi programmatically and wait until it not enabled

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

I want to send data over local network using wifi. Before sending data I check the wifi state, and, if it not enabled, ask the user  and turn wifi on.
 The problem is if I turn wifi on and try to use it immediately, I have got an error cause the wifi need some time to be turned on.

So, as I think, I need to turn wifi on and set the handler which will be called when wifi goes to enabled state. But WifiManager doesn't provide such methods with handlers. How I can catch changing of wifi state?

**UPD**

How I turn wifi on:

```
WifiManager wifi = WifiUtils.getWifi( getApplicationContext() );
if (WifiUtils.isWifiEnabled( wifi)) return true;
wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
//---
public static WifiManager getWifi( Context ctx) 
{
    return (WifiManager)ctx.getSystemService(ctx.WIFI_SERVICE);
}

public static boolean isWifiEnabled( WifiManager wifi)
{
    if (wifi==null) return false;
    if (wifi.getWifiState()!=wifi.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you want to check if wifi is connected or not You can use this

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(
        Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {

}
else{
//ask your user to turn on wifi
}
```

Now if you want to check whether the device can access internet even if wifi is on, then you could do something like

```
if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {

HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == 200){

                //internet access
            }
            else {
                //no internet access
            }
}
```

If you want to handle wifi state changes then you can try [BroadcastReceiver when wifi or 3g network state changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed) or [Android: Getting Notified of Connectivity Changes](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-getting-notified-of-connectivity-changes/)

However if you want to turn wifi on programmatically refer [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871762/android-turning-on-wifi-programmatically).Basically you will need to do something like this

```
WifiManager wManager = (WifiManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

wManager.setWifiEnabled(booleanValue); //true for on and false for off
```

And of course you will need to add necessary permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I think http connection to someone is not a good way itself, and also because I need access to the local network only. Main problem is that I don't know how to handle wifi state changes after I turn it on

Comment: Agree with you regarding httpconnection. However to handle wifi state changes did you refer [BroadcastReceiver when wifi or 3g network state changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed)?

Comment: What i find is your solution lies in the question of that link which i provided.The OP has posted his complete working code.You can refer that and your problem is solved.